# multiple including and excluding condition in regular expressions in r

Tags: r, regex, performance

I have a data with over 10 million observations, with a string variable `dat_text`. I am trying to give an indicator variable (IV) for each observation.

The IV will be 1 when the string `dat_text` **includes** any form that contains that any of the string in `pat_text` **AND** **excludes** any form that contains that any of the string in `ex_text` (Please refer to the EDIT for the meaning). I am trying to implement this in R.

```
dat_text <- c("dbhgfadgdfgc", "sdfdsfsdgdfxgfydz", "fqdfsbfdjhdhts","dbhgfghfadgdfgc", "sdfdghsfsdgdfxgfydz", "fqdfsbfdjhfghdhts", "fdsafgdjfx", "dfdoslfspd")
ex_text <- c("fgh", "opl")
pat_text <- c("abc", "xyz", "jbq")
```

I have created a function with loop built in:

```
myfunction <- function(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text){
# =========PART 1: pat_text========================
logic_tem <- list()
for(i in 1:length(pat_text)){# for each phrase in "pat_text"
  temp <- list()
  for(t in 1:nchar(pat_text[i])){# for each character in the phrase
    temp[[t]] <- grepl(substring(pat_text[i], t, t), dat_text) 
  }
  # Use "AND" to connect multiple logic vectors
  temp <- do.call(cbind, temp)
  logic_tem[[i]] <- (rowSums(temp) == dim(temp)[2L])
}

logic_tem <- do.call(cbind, logic_tem)
logic_pattext <- rowSums(logic_tem) > 0

# =========PART 2: ex_text========================
logic_tem <- list()
for(i in 1:length(ex_text)){# for each phrase in "ex_text"
  temp <- list()
  for(t in 1:nchar(ex_text[i])){# for each character in the phrase
    temp[[t]] <- grepl(substring(ex_text[i], t, t), dat_text) 
  }
  temp <- do.call(cbind, temp)
  logic_tem[[i]] <- (rowSums(temp) == dim(temp)[2L])
}
# Use "OR" to connect multiple logic vectors
logic_tem <- do.call(cbind, logic_tem)
logic_extext <- rowSums(logic_tem) > 0

# =========PART 3: combine the two parts=========
return(logic_pattext & !logic_extext)
}
```

This function works well:

```
> myfunction(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But  turns out to be rather slow and inefficient when I implement this on my original data. I am asking if anybody could provide any clue on improving the performance of this function in R? Thanks

**EDIT** It was my bad that I did not clear state "any permutation of any string". By that phrase, I actually means that the observation contains all letters in that string. If the `pat_text` is `fgh`, then the following phrases all meet the requirement:

```
"fgh", "00000f00000g00000h", "00000g00000h00000f", "000000h00000f00000g"
```

Actually the `0`s in the above pattern can be any characters or numbers. I realised that this question actually become a totally different question after this edition. I really didn't realized that it was a totally different question when I wrote that. I am so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized approach to your function:

```
myfunction <- function(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text){

    sep_pat_text = strsplit(pat_text,"")
    result = lapply(sep_pat_text, FUN  = function(k){
        testLetter = lapply(k, grepl, x = dat_text)
        resultLetter = do.call(cbind, testLetter)
        apply(resultLetter, 1, all)
    })
    include = apply(do.call(cbind, result), 1, any)


    sep_ex_text = strsplit(ex_text,"")
    result = lapply(sep_ex_text, FUN  = function(k){
        testLetter = lapply(k, grepl, x = dat_text)
        resultLetter = do.call(cbind, testLetter)
        apply(resultLetter, 1, all)
    })
    dontInclude = apply(do.call(cbind, result), 1, any)

    return(!dontInclude & include)
}
```

Applying this function to your input samples results:

```
> myfunction(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I can't guarantee that this will perform better, but give it a try and comment your results.

**Edit:** This function can be simplified by combining duplicated code into an inner function.

```
myfunction <- function(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text){
    testLetters = function(text, pattern){
        sep_pat = strsplit(pattern, "")
        result = lapply(sep_pat, FUN  = function(k){
            testLetter = lapply(k, grepl, x = text)
            resultLetter = do.call(cbind, testLetter)
            apply(resultLetter, 1, all)
        })
        return(apply(do.call(cbind, result), 1, any))
    }    

    include = testLetters(dat_text, pat_text)
    dontInclude = testLetters(dat_text, ex_text)

    return(!dontInclude & include)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing help. I will run a benchmark test and post the result in few days.

Comment: I have added the benchmarking result as an answer at the end of this page. It seems that the answer by the original poster is faster than your answer, which is not as expected. Please feel free to test that code in case I made any mistakes and confirm the replicability of the codes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@R. Schifini I ran a benchmarking code to test which function runs faster, and here is my result. You can try running the same code to confirm the replicability of the codes.

## Generate data

```
dat_text <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(10^6, 5)
ex_text <- c("fgh", "opl")
pat_text <- c("abc", "xyz", "jbq")
```

#### Function 1: function provided by the original poster

```
myfunction1 <- function(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text){
# =========PART 1: pat_text========================
logic_tem <- list()
for(i in 1:length(pat_text)){# for each phrase in "pat_text"
  temp <- list()
  for(t in 1:nchar(pat_text[i])){# for each character in the phrase
    temp[[t]] <- grepl(substring(pat_text[i], t, t), dat_text) 
  }
  # Use "AND" to connect multiple logic vectors
  temp <- do.call(cbind, temp)
  logic_tem[[i]] <- (rowSums(temp) == dim(temp)[2L])
}

logic_tem <- do.call(cbind, logic_tem)
logic_pattext <- rowSums(logic_tem) > 0

# =========PART 2: ex_text========================
logic_tem <- list()
for(i in 1:length(ex_text)){# for each phrase in "ex_text"
  temp <- list()
  for(t in 1:nchar(ex_text[i])){# for each character in the phrase
    temp[[t]] <- grepl(substring(ex_text[i], t, t), dat_text) 
  }
  temp <- do.call(cbind, temp)
  logic_tem[[i]] <- (rowSums(temp) == dim(temp)[2L])
}
# Use "OR" to connect multiple logic vectors
logic_tem <- do.call(cbind, logic_tem)
logic_extext <- rowSums(logic_tem) > 0

# =========PART 3: combine the two parts=========
return(logic_pattext & !logic_extext)
}
```

#### Function2: the 1st function by @R. Schifini

```
myfunction2 <- function(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text){
sep_pat_text = strsplit(pat_text,"")
result = lapply(sep_pat_text, FUN = function(k){
testLetter = lapply(k, grepl, x = dat_text)
resultLetter = do.call(cbind, testLetter)
apply(resultLetter, 1, all)
})
include = apply(do.call(cbind, result), 1, any)
sep_ex_text = strsplit(ex_text,"")
result = lapply(sep_ex_text, FUN = function(k){
testLetter = lapply(k, grepl, x = dat_text)
resultLetter = do.call(cbind, testLetter)
apply(resultLetter, 1, all)
})
dontInclude = apply(do.call(cbind, result), 1, any)
return(!dontInclude & include)
}
```

#### Function3: the 2nd function by @R. Schifini

```
myfunction3 <- function(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text){
testLetters = function(text, pattern){
sep_pat = strsplit(pattern, "")
result = lapply(sep_pat, FUN = function(k){
testLetter = lapply(k, grepl, x = text)
resultLetter = do.call(cbind, testLetter)
apply(resultLetter, 1, all)
})
return(apply(do.call(cbind, result), 1, any))
}
include = testLetters(dat_text, pat_text)
dontInclude = testLetters(dat_text, ex_text)
return(!dontInclude & include)
}
```

## Benchmarking

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
myfunction1(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text),
myfunction2(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text),
myfunction3(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text))

>## Unit: seconds
>## expr min lq mean median uq max neval
>## myfunction1(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text) 3.284922 3.443022 3.605378 3.594186 3.698748 4.041584 100
>## myfunction2(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text) 12.134576 13.457712 13.802636 13.710624 14.765376 16.084844 100
>## myfunction3(pat_text, ex_text, dat_text) 12.136296 13.522227 13.812180 13.719780 14.662117 17.126667 100
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. As I said, I couldn't guarantee that converting your for loops to a vectorized code would be faster. In fact, I have experienced the same thing in other situations. I understand what you are aiming for, but I don't see how to simplify the regular expressions or your for loops. One suggestion, run the `ex_text` pattern first and remove from `dat_text` those that match before checking `pat_text`, you will have fewer cases to check.

Comment: @R. Schifini Thanks for your help. The result really doesn't matter. I actually learnt a lot from your coding. I have never thought of using `strsplit` and `lapply` to vectorize the function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use some of the `tidyverse` tools, notably `stringr::str_detect`, regular expressions, and `dplyr`. Without the original data, I don't know how much faster it will be, but I think most likely considerably. It would be something like the following. You can combine parts to make it shorter, but I think this is most readable. I am also interpreting 
"any permutation of any string" to mean, for example, that individual strings in `dat_text` cannot include `"fgh"` from `ex_text` but can include `"hgf"` for example, and that `"fgh"` must be entirely in one string to count.

```
library(tidyverse)
# Make dat_text a column in a data frame
dat_txt_tbl <- tibble(dat_text)
# Make regular expressions
ex_rgx <- str_c(ex_text, sep = "|")
pat_rgx <- str_c(pat_text, sep = "|")
dat_txt_tbl %>%
    mutate(inc_pat_txt = str_detect(dat_text, pat_rgx)) %>%
    mutate(inc_ex_txt = str_detect(ex_text, ex_rgx)) %>%
    mutate(IV = inc_pat_txt & (!inc_ex_txt))
```

IV is hopefully what you want. Without an example it's hard to debug though.

Comment: Thanks for providing help. Actually the problem turns out to be much harder than this answer can solve. Please refer to the EDIT if you are interested in it and if you have time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Updating per the new definition of the question. Not sure if this will be faster, but you might be able to pick and choose some of the techniques from this approach:

```
library(stringr)

pat_text <- c("abc", "xyz", "jbq")
ex_text <- c("fgh", "opl")
dat_text <- c("dbhgfadgdfgc", "sdfdsfsdgdfxgfydz", "fqdfsbfdjhdhts","dbhgfghfadgdfgc", "sdfdghsfsdgdfxgfydz", "fqdfsbfdjhfghdhts", "fdsafgdjfx", "dfdoslfspd")

pat_chars <- strsplit(pat_text, "")
ex_chars <- strsplit(ex_text, "")

mat_pat <- lapply(dat_text, function(x) sapply(pat_chars, str_detect, string = x))
mat_ex <- lapply(dat_text, function(x) sapply(ex_chars, str_detect, string = x))

match_pat <- apply(sapply(mat_pat, function(x) apply(x, 2, all)), 2, any)
match_ex <- apply(sapply(mat_ex, function(x) apply(x, 2, all)), 2, any)

result <- match_pat & !match_ex
result
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Old code that answered the original (un-edited) question

*NOTE: Keeping the following code because it illustrates some concepts in case someone stumbles upon this question.*

So I'm not sure if your current method is working correctly because I do not find any matches of `pat_text`? And `FALSE` *and* `anything` will always be `FALSE`. Anyway, I think this is what you want. Could probably be optimized and cleaned up -- the crux is making all the permutations.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(combinat)
library(stringr)

get_permutations <- function(text) {
  strsplit(text, "") %>%
    map(permn) %>%
    data.frame(check.names = FALSE) %>%
    map(paste0, collapse = "") %>%
    unname %>% 
    unlist
}

pat_perm <- get_permutations(pat_text)
pat_perm
# [1] "abc" "acb" "cab" "cba" "bca" "bac" "xyz" "xzy" "zxy" "zyx" "yzx" "yxz" "jbq" "jqb" "qjb" "qbj"
# [17] "bqj" "bjq"

ex_perm <- get_permutations(ex_text)
ex_perm
# [1] "fgh" "fhg" "hfg" "hgf" "ghf" "gfh" "opl" "olp" "lop" "lpo" "plo" "pol"

match_pat_perm <- str_detect(dat_text, paste0(pat_perm, collapse = "|"))
match_ex_perm <- str_detect(dat_text, paste0(ex_perm, collapse = "|"))

result <- match_pat_perm & !match_ex_perm
result

# Included to show how you might get the locations.
str_locate_all(dat_text, paste0(pat_perm, collapse = "|")) 
str_locate_all(dat_text, paste0(ex_perm, collapse = "|"))
```

*Note: your questions states the result should be an integer, but your example suggests otherwise; regardless, you could always do `as.integer(result)`.*

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't realize that I messed up the inclusion and exclusion criteria. Actually I meant any form that contains that string, NOT the permutation of that string. Please see the edit of the question. I am so sorry for not explaining the question correctly.

Comment: @MiaoCai Thank you for the clarification. I went ahead and added a different solution -- looks similar to R. Schifini's, so you'll probably want to do some benchmarks. Obviously, you could remove some of the duplication by wrapping things up in a function, but since it was only a few lines, I left the full-blown approach.